# make background view still interactable but have an overlay as well on top

Tags: typescript, react-native

Hi I am unable to find any answer to the question I raised
I'm trying to have 2 views overlap but make the background view still interactive
I'm using position absolute for the foreground view

```
overlapView: {
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      marginBottom: bottom,
      paddingTop: top,
      position: 'absolute',
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
    },
backgroundView: {
flex: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already interactive. I have generated an example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@sadiac/grumpy-edamame) but it would be helpful if you could share your code.